# Как реализовать связь многие ко многим с одной моделью? (Laravel)

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, eloquent, связь

Столкнулся с такой проблемой ... у меня есть модель - Article - (там все товары - мобильные телефоны, чехлы, наушники и т.п. )

Я хочу чтобы на странице карточки товара  отображать к телефону - наушники, чехлы ( то есть реализовать связь многие ко многим ), но получается все товары из одной таблицы - модели.

А как же мне тогда реализовать такую связь - саму к себе?В официальной документации не нашёл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам никто не запрещает создать связующую таблицу например "article_merge", где в качестве ключей будут данные из одной таблицы. Например:

article_id   child_id

1(телефон) - 1(чехол)

1(телефон) - 4(наушник)

...

Даже наложить ограничения с помощью `foreign`. Далее для связи модели используйте как-то так главное укажите связующую таблицу:

```
public function addition_products() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article', 'article_merge', 'article_id', 'child_id');
}
```

Ну и собственно получать данные как

```
$article = Article::find(1);
$addition = $article->addition_products;
```

**P.S** если где-то очепятка, или немного с вызовом накосячил, извиняюсь! нет под рукой данных и проекта, чтобы сделать рабочую модель и более точно описать решение и понять если вдруг ошибся. Но на мысль надеюсь Вас навёл.

Comment: Так а как мне положить данные в этот addition_products? Получается с помощью кода я получил массив с коллекциями)

"array:2 [▼
  0 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#351 ▶}
  1 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#355 ▶}
]"
, где в коллекциях я получаю ID тех товаров, которые нужно положить в эту связующую таблицу. В БД есть такие столбцы -  id article_id merge_id, Где в article_id нужно чтобы всегда ложился id моей записи, которую создаю или редактирую, а в merge_id - ID тех записей, что получаю в коллекциях.

Comment: П.С. на мысль навели... но пока работаем над реализацией ))

Comment: теперь получаю уже такой массив - array:2 [▼
  0 => 109
  1 => 111
], уже легче

Comment: В общем, удалось решить эту задачу)... покрайней мере добавление, надо ещё апдейт просмотреть)

Comment: @ОлексійСлєпцов добрый день. Извините что долго не отвечал, работаю то же. Рад что Разобрались и всё получилось!

Comment: спасибо! Всё уже получилось, правильно меня на вели на мысль)